# R - Can't get ksmooth or the KernSmooth package to work

Tags: r, smoothing

I can't seem to get the ksmooth function or KernSmooth package to give me anything for the following example:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 3*sin(x/10)+rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

The ksmooth function does nothing and just gives me back the same points. Using the KernSmooth package all I can seem to get is a linear approximation.

Why does `ksmooth(x,y,kernel="normal",bandwidth=0.5)` just give me back the same points? Also how do I use the KernSmooth package? Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe what you'd like to do with the package? Do you just want to add a smoothed line to the plot? If so can just add a smoothed line via 
`scatter.smooth(x,y)`.  You can do the same thing (with a little more work) using the kernsmooth package `bkde` provides a function for computing the "binned kernel density estimate", different x and y coordinates that provide a probability estimate for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selected bandwidth = 0.5 is too small.

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 3*sin(x/10)+rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
lines(ksmooth(x, y, "normal", bandwidth = 5), col = "red")

library(KernSmooth)
fit <- locpoly(x, y, bandwidth = 5)
lines(fit, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. How would I use the KernSmooth package to get the same result?

Comment: Can we use the other function in KernSmooth to do a similar thing? Do any of them yield the same result as ksmooth()? I find the KernSmooth documentation confusing.

Comment: @AndrewK `locpoly` does the same thing as `ksmooth`. Other functions in KernSmooth are for density estimation.

Comment: @AndrewK I also looked to get the same result as `stats::ksmooth()` with and found that using a `bandwidth` 2.8 times smaller with `KernSmooth::locpoly()` does a good job at replicating the original fit.